# Background colour will not fill entire background to edge of border

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I need some help with some CSS I have coded. I have a menu aligned on the right however when I try to fill the background colour, it does not fill to the border edge. I understand that the problem is to do with the borders and that there is a gap between each menu item however I cannot seem to figure out the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

PHP/HTML:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="menu">
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header-menu')); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header, #menu ul {
   background-color: #fff;
   text-align: right;
   line-height: 65px;
   list-style-type: none;
}

#menu {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(231, 76, 60,0.6);
}

#menu li {
   display: inline-block;
   border-left: 1px dotted rgba(231, 76, 60,0.6);
}

#menu a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #c0392b;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#menu a:hover {
   background-color: #c0392b;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: You should reproduce and demonstrate your issue in jsfiddle

Comment: Do you have a link to the site? I would try to move the border to the link and not the list-item.

Comment: Yeah it is http://georetro.com/wp

Comment: display: inline-block spacing problem. More: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Now my border bottom is not connecting to the other borders - http://georetro.com/wp

Answer (score 1):

Gap between your menu items is just a character space. You should modify your HTML to exlude spaces between elements or just set font-size:0 for #menu and then set correct font size back for links.

```
#header, #menu ul {
   background-color: #fff;
   text-align: right;
   line-height: 65px;
   list-style-type: none;
}

#menu {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(231, 76, 60,0.6);
   font-size: 0;
}

#menu li {
   display: inline-block;
   border-left: 1px dotted rgba(231, 76, 60,0.6);
}

#menu a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #c0392b;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
}

#menu a:hover {
   background-color: #c0392b;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you applied list elements `inline-block` which is a whitespace dependent method, it is dependent on font setting so whitespace is coming.

To solve specify `font-size` to inline-block elements and set `font-size:0` to parent container.

Update your code as follows:

```css
#menu {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(231, 76, 60,0.6);
   font-size:0
}
#menu li {
   display: inline-block;
   border-left: 1px dotted rgba(231, 76, 60,0.6);
   font-size:14px
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have now completed this, however now my border bottom is not connecting to the other borders - http://georetro.com/wp

Comment: which browser you checked?